# How to display the JSON data through controls using PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, json, powerapp

I have a list with one of the multiple text type field always contains JSON Value. Now I am creating the PowerApps form to display individual list item details along with the JSON value though some controls over the form instead of raw JSON value.

Kindly help me to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try creating Collection/variable using JSON value and using it to show on Power Apps controls?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response !
No, I haven't tried as I don't know how to iterate JSON to create the collection or any ready-made function which does that over PowerApp form.
I am new to PowerApps. Any guide to parse JSON and store in a collection variable and then assigning the variable to any control to display

Comment: Hello Ganesh, Any idea on how to convert the JSON to collection in Power app?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427144/how-to-convert-json-to-collection-in-power-apps) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Parse-JSON-string-in-Power-APPS/td-p/381832) if it helps.